# How to find the index of n largest elements in column vector, Python

Tags: python, numpy, vector

Is there a built-in function or a very simple way of finding the index of n largest elements in column vector ?

```
v = [[5]
     [3]
     [1]
     [2]
     [4]]
```

Find the index of the largest 3 elements?

I count the duplicates more than once, and the output should be a list of the indices of those largest numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten the array and get the indices of the top n

```
>>> arr.flatten().argsort()[-3:][::-1]
array([0, 4, 1])
```

Comment: I would use `ravel()` instead of `flatten()`. It's more memory efficient and just changes the view rather than creating another array.